# Why are write.csv and write.table converting my character list into an integer one?

Tags: r

I have a character list of all the zip codes in the United States, and I want to write them to a .csv or .txt file.  There are such zip codes as "01001" for example that begin with a "0".  This is problematic because after I writing the file and then reading it, the zip code becomes 1001 (integer).

Why does...

```
zip <- c("01001","01002")      
write.csv(zip,file=file)  
A=read.csv(file=file)
```

this yield A=(1001,1002)

Comment: You can specify `colClasses='character'` ie. `read.csv(file, colClasses='character')` assuming there is a single column

Comment: As to the "why", `read.csv()` uses `type.convert()` to determine the values.  `type.convert(zip)` results in numerics.

Comment: Thanks!  I was reading everything about write.csv and it didn't occur to me that the problem was in the read.csv